# Why storing a double expression in a variable before a cast to int can lead to different results than casting it directly?

Tags: c, casting, floating-point

I write this short program to test the conversion from double to int:

```
int main() {
    int a;
    int d; 
    double b = 0.41;

    /* Cast from variable. */
    double c = b * 100.0;
    a = (int)(c);

    /* Cast expression directly. */
    d = (int)(b * 100.0);

    printf("c = %f \n", c);
    printf("a = %d \n", a);
    printf("d = %d \n", d);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
c = 41.000000 
a = 41 
d = 40
```

Why do `a` and `d` have different values even though they are both the product of `b` and `100`?

Comment: http://floating-point-gui.de

Comment: Side note: `a = (int)(c);` There is no need to the parenthesis around `c`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get around rounding issues in floating point arithmetic in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339394/how-to-get-around-rounding-issues-in-floating-point-arithmetic-in-c)

Comment: @MarounMaroun Nor is there any need for the explicit cast.

Comment: @H2CO3 Indeed. `a` is already an `int`.

Comment: A quick dirty run proved Java has no such issue. What's the difference here?

Comment: @ZiyaoWei That's what we call an "implementation detail".

Comment: @CarlNorum That link isn't loading for me. Do you know of another place with the same relevant content?

Comment: @H2CO3 Surprising to me at least - I imagined IEEE 754 took care of these kind of issues, and C++ and Java should be conform to that.

Comment: `d = (int)(b * 100.000);` is apparently computed at greater precision than that of `double` (that's allowed), resulting in a value slightly smaller than 41. When that's stored as a `double`, it becomes exactly 41.0.

Comment: @EricFinn [This](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) might be a more reliable link, although it delves into the matter in much more detail.

Comment: And now it's being upvoted... ***Whyyyyy?***

Comment: @H2CO3 I suspect people think it's an interesting question, as it involves behavior that I expect many people *wouldn't* expect.

Comment: @EricFinn Except that floating point rounding questions have been beaten to death on Stack Overflow and the Internet in general.

Comment: @ajp15243 That's true, but most of the time people just throw that Goldberg paper at the question, which is not really helpful.

Comment: @ajp15243, maybe so but this is a particularly interesting wrinkle on the subject. Not that it hasn't come up too, but generally using the same inputs you expect the same output.

Comment: @H2CO3 The OP doesn't yet have the downvote privilege (requires 125 rep). It was somebody else.

Comment: @DanielFischer Correct. I didn't even notice that :(

Comment: @ZiyaoWei Yes, I agree that throwing the Goldberg paper link at them and walking away is not the best way to answer it lol. But I think H2CO3's point is that the question appears to have not been well researched before posting, although to Mark's point I'm not sure how many people have specifically asked about it with casting involved (I'm sure there are questions out there).

Comment: @ajp15243 Ha, just noticed the link was provided by you this time:) No offense really, that's a perfectly good read.

Comment: @ZiyaoWei Well that's why it's a comment and not an answer :). No offense taken.

Comment: Give us the precise compiler version, command and OS, and the `objdump -D` output.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The C standard allows a C implementation to compute floating-point operations with more precision than the nominal type. For example, the Intel 80-bit floating-point format may be used when the type in the source code is `double`, for the IEEE-754 64-bit format. In this case, the behavior can be completely explained by assuming the C implementation uses `long double` (80 bit) whenever it can and converts to `double` when the C standard requires it.

I conjecture what happens in this case is:

- In `double b = 0.41;`, `0.41` is converted to `double` and stored in `b`. The conversion results in a value slightly less than .41.
- In `double c = b * 100.0000;`, `b * 100.0000` is evaluated in `long double`. This produces a value slightly less than 41.
- That expression is used to initialize `c`. The C standard requires that it be converted to `double` at this point. Because the value is so close to 41, the conversion produces exactly 41. So `c` is 41.
- `a = (int)(c);` produces 41, as normal.
- In `d = (int)(b * 100.000);`, we have the same multiplication as before. The value is the same as before, something slightly less than 41. However, this value is not assigned to or used to intialize a `double`, so no conversion to `double` occurs. Instead, it is converted to `int`. Since the value is slightly less than 41, the conversion produces 40.

Comment: I'd say this is exactly as ugly as usual. The value `0.41` cannot be represented exactly in binary floating-point; the stored value will be either slightly less than or slightly greater than the mathematical value. Details about `double` vs. `long double` and storing extra precision might affect the results in this particular case, but in general you *can't* necessarily expect `0.41` multiplied by 100 and converted to `int` to yield `41`, whatever else you do.

Comment: C says this: *(C99, 6.3.1.p8) "The values of floating operands and of the results of floating expressions may be represented in greater precision and range than that required by the type;"*

Comment: @KeithThompson, the rules employed by IEEE arithmetic should give reproducible results even when rounding is occurring. It doesn't matter if 0.41 gets rounded down if the multiplication rounds it back up again.

Comment: @KeithThompson: By “usual”, I was comparing to similar questions posed on Stack Overflow. Usually when somebody asks on Stack Overflow why two apparently identical expressions yield different results, it is simply that one of them has been rounded to `double` and the other has not. The issue of what you can expect from floating-point operations is entirely separate. If the low-level floating-point operations are the **same**, the results are the **same**. In this case, the high-level source code is the **same**, but the results are **different**. That is the fault of C, not floating-point.

Comment: Eric, since we have `d = (int)(b * 100.000);`, it is to be expected that it uses the `double` value of `0.41`. Multiply that with `100.0L` and you're likely to get something like `40.9999999999999975575093458246556110680103302001953125`.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Yes, I believe I figured it out. The behavior is completely explained by the compiler using `long double` whenever it can and converting to `double` when compelled by the C standard. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: C says that (C99, 5.1.2.3p12) [...] In particular, casts and assignments are required to perform their specified conversion [..]" With `gcc` and `-std=c99`, if we force the cast by having: d = (int)(double)(b * 100.000);, `gcc` is now giving the expected same result (same with `-std=c89` and `-fexcess-precision=standard`). Older `gcc` (< 4.5) would not give the right answer when the cast was present and `-fexcess-precision=standard` option has been added and enabled for `-std=c99` in http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=323 patch. So it shows your conjecture is totally correct.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler can infer that `c` has to be initialized with `0.41 * 100.0` and does that better than the calculation of `d`.

Comment: When computed as IEEE754 `double`s, `0.41 * 100` is exactly 41.

Comment: Yes, floating point has odd behaviour. The compiler however also evaluates constants and generates `double c = 41.0;` by smart data flow analysis.

Comment: Confused - but then why d is 40?

Comment: @Joop My point was that if the computation at run-time is done at `double` precision [assuming the ubiquitous format], the result is exactly 41 too.

Comment: Sorry my guess is 0.41 has no exact binary presentation, finite summation over 1/64, 1/128, ... and hence 100 * 0.41 might happen to be slighty less (or more) than 41.

Comment: @JoopEggen Of course 0.41 cannot be exactly represented as a binary floating point number. But `0.409999999999999975575093458246556110680103302001953125` times 100, rounded to 53 significant bits yields exactly 41.0.

Comment: @DanielFischer yes but that last bit rounding is a haphazard thing isn't it. You seem more experienced to the standard; I just know about the extra bytes under calculation, and the last bit issue. Maybe you may formulate an own answer. Would be interesting.

Comment: I'm afraid my comments here contributed to the downvotes you received, I'm sorry for that if that is so, it was not my intention. If the FPU runs according to the IEEE754 specs, there is nothing haphazard in the rounding for plain arithmetic. It's also consistent if it uses the x87 extended (80 bit) type. It's just not always easy to find out what mode the compiler uses when.

Comment: @DanielFischer one thing learned/confirmed outweights -100 points on SO. I would guess too, that compiler options might be set or some other thing.

Answer (score 1):

The crux of the problem is that `0.41` is not exactly representable in IEEE 754 64-bit binary floating point. The actual value (with only enough precision to show the relevant part) is `0.409999999999999975575...`, while `100` can be represented exactly. Multiplying these together should yield `40.9999999999999975575...`, which is again not quite representable. <strike>In the likely case that the rounding mode is towards nearest, zero, or negative infinity, this should be rounded to `40.9999999999999964...`. When cast to an int, this is rounded to `40`.</strike>

The compiler is allowed to do calculations with higher precision, however, and in particular may replace the multiplication in the assignment of `c` with a direct store of the computed value.

---

Edit: I miscalculated the largest representable number less than 41, the correct value is approximately `40.99999999999999289...`. As both Eric Postpischil and Daniel Fischer correctly point out, even the value calculated as a double should be rounded to `41` unless the rounding mode is towards zero or negative infinity. Do you know what the rounding mode is? It makes a difference, as [this code sample](http://ideone.com/T2PpKX) shows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fenv.h>
#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON

int main(void)
{
    int roundMode = fegetround( );

    volatile double d1;
    volatile double d2;
    volatile double result;
    volatile int rounded;

    fesetround(FE_TONEAREST);

    d1 = 0.41;
    d2 = 100;
    result = d1 * d2;
    rounded = result;

    printf("nearest rounded=%i\n", rounded);

    fesetround(FE_TOWARDZERO);

    d1 = 0.41;
    d2 = 100;
    result = d1 * d2;
    rounded = result;

    printf("zero rounded=%i\n", rounded);

    fesetround(roundMode);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
nearest rounded=41
zero rounded=40
```